# CodeIgniter PHP Mail Function Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a script which sends an email to myself from a contact page:

```
if($_POST["submit"] == "Send Message")
{
    $to = "myemail@mm.com";
    $subject = "Message received from Contact Us";
    $message = "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>";
    $message .= "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>";
    $message .= "Message: ".$_POST["message"]."<br>";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    echo mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $messageSent = TRUE;
}
```

It does actually echo 1. But I am not receiving any emails in my email account (gmail). I am using Codeigniter I saw there's an email library, but this should work shouldn't it?

I have a couple of other similar forms, I don't really want to integrate this library if I already have normal PHP to do it.

I know that my server is capable of sending emails because I've done it before, i have a feeling this is codeigniter related. If there is no other options, I suppose I can use the library and change the code. Any advice on this will help! Thank you :)

Comment: Try doing just `\n` rather than `\r\n`.  I believe PHP can get itself muddled by this.

Comment: this is a good point - although seems an old issue judging by a quick google, Can't say I've ever experienced it myself though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not CI related as you aren't making use of any CI functionality.

any reason you ~aren't~ using the email helper?

in CI:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('contact-form');
}
else
{
    $this->load->library('email');

    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
   $message= $this->input->post('message');

    $this->email->from($email, $name);
    $this->email->to('you@domain.com');

    $this->email->subject('Subject');
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        //redirect('contact-us/thanks', 'location');
    }
   else
   {
    echo 'Something went wrong...';
   }

}
```

also note that mail returns true/false depending on if php was able to SEND It. there's no way of telling if the message was ever received.

try it in CI - see if there is any difference in outcome

Comment: you'll need the form_validation helper also, i omitted that from my original code. see the edited version

Comment: DONT USE CI HELPER ITS CRAP SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262794/codeigniter-email-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter can't be responsible for your problems because mail() is a php function which can't be overwritten except by some fancy string preprocessing before including a php source file.

Comment: try var_dump(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)); if it says true then mail delivered your email to the outgoing server and the problem lays either in your header or at googlemail

Comment: BTW do you downvote every answer that doesn't give you the propper and full solution directly?

Comment: :) Well I ask a question and I would like an answer

Comment: I agree with Pete here. Your answer is just a comment, and so it should be a reply to the question.